# How to change a spacing between the lines of a notebook?

Tags: formatting, cdf-format, stylesheet

My question is formulated above. However, to precise a bit I would like to split it into two sub-questions:

1. It it possible to define the spacing in the current notebook/CDF pressumably through the Option Inspector. I have in mind that this definition should persist in case the notebook is given away and opened on another machine, where Mathematica or PDF Player are ignorant of my settings?
2. How to control the line spacing through the StyleSheet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`LineSpacing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LineSpacing.html?q=LineSpacing&lang=en), you can use it this way:

```
1;
2;
3;
SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], LineSpacing -> {2, 0}]
```

> [image]

Or via `OptionsInspector`:

> [image]